# Log viewing tool for ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, logs

I am looking for a log viewing tool in ubuntu .
Not just ordinary text viewing tool , I need to monitor logs in real time.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: sorry I was out of town I know if it helps I should upvote that  and thanks for reminding me  . :D

Answer (score 2):

You can open up a terminal and use

`tail -f /path/to/log/file.txt`

This will append output in real time.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [gnome-system-log](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-system-log/):

[image]

Comment: +1. Also, if you are using Kubuntu, you can use ksystemlog.